# AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-4)

Tags: c++

I was trying [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/) leetcode problem when i encountered this error. The problem seems to occur when i introduce a vector v and try to delete and element from that vector. Earlier, i was simply deleting the element from the nums vector and passing it again recursively. And that code compiled without any error but it modified the original nums vector so it gave wrong answer. I can't seem to understand why there is a problem when i do the same thing with another vector v.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void generatePermutations(vector<int> nums, vector<int> output, vector<vector<int>> &ans) {
        vector<int> v = nums;
        if(nums.size() == 0) {
            ans.push_back(output);
            return;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {
            output.push_back(nums[j]);
            v.erase(v.begin() + j);
            generatePermutations(v, output, ans);
        }
        
    }

    vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        vector<int> output;
        generatePermutations(nums, output, ans);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

and here is the error:

```
==23==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-4)
    #7 0x7f3eeb6cb082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x602000000158 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x602000000150,0x602000000158)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #7 0x7f3eeb6cb082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
==23==ABORTING
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Lets take a very simple case, where `nums.size() == 2`. Then you will erase `v.begin() + 0`, which leads to the next iteration `v.begin() + 1` being out of bounds.